# Generics calling different function based on type

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a problem that I think would benefit from some generics, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around. 
I have a FileImporter Class

```
public class FileImporter<T>
{
     public async Task ImportFile(string filePath)
        {
            StreamReader fileReader;
            String fileLine;

            fileReader = new StreamReader(filePath);
            List<T> entityList = new List<T>();

            if ((fileLine = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                headerNames = fileLine.ToLower().Split(',').ToList();

                try
                {
                    while ((fileLine = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        lineInfo = fileLine.Split(',').ToList();

            //Need something here to define a new Entity and load it from the file.  
            //This would of course be unique to each entity type        

                        entityList.Add(entity);
                    }


                    await _context.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(entityList);

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I'm trying to get away from duplicating all the code in the Import File function, because the only difference is adding creating the entity based on the values in the file.

Comment: To create an instance of the entity, you could use `new T()` (would require to add the constraint `where T : new()` in the class declaration) or you could use ´Activator.CreateInstance()` to do that. Do your enttities derive from a base class? How would you know how to populate that instances?

Comment: If you do a few things, it should work.  First, make sure that all your entities have a default constructor.  Then constraint `T` with `new()`.  Then, have all your entities either implement the same interface or inherit from the same class.  In the definition of that type, have an instance method that will take an "empty" object and create from whatever your import method can feed it.  If you constrain `T` to implement that type, then you can call that method

Comment: Ah...didn't know about the new() constraint.  I think that will do it.  I'll make them all implement an IImportable interface with a Load method.